# Python: After the function is called once, if I called again it will print 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def data_mining (text_file, start, end):
    count = 0
    total_value = 0
    average = 0
    for file_line_number, line in enumerate(text_file):
        if (file_line_number % 2) == 0:
            value = line[start:end]
            value = int(value)
            total_value += value
            count += 1
    return total_value, count


def main ():
    #Main program.
    text_file = open("93cars.dat.txt", "r")

    city_mpg = data_mining(text_file, 52, 54)
    highway_mpg = data_mining(text_file, 55, 57)
    midrange_price = data_mining(text_file, 42, 44)

    print (city_mpg)
    print (highway_mpg)
    print (midrange_price)

main()
```

I am trying to make data mining in a text but after I call the data_mining function once, the next time I call it it will return just 0. I tried to make a copy of text_file by writing text_file2 = text_file[:] but it returned an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def data_mining (text_file, start, end):
    count = 0
    total_value = 0
    average = 0
    for file_line_number, line in enumerate(text_file):
        if (file_line_number % 2) == 0:
            value = line[start:end]
            value = int(value)
            total_value += value
            count += 1
    return total_value, count


def main ():
    #Main program.
    text_file = open("93cars.dat.txt", "r")
    city_mpg = data_mining(text_file, 52, 54)
    text_file.seek(0) #reset the file pointer to 0
    highway_mpg = data_mining(text_file, 55, 57)
    text_file.seek(0) #reset the file pointer to 0
    midrange_price = data_mining(text_file, 42, 44)

    print (city_mpg)
    print (highway_mpg)
    print (midrange_price)

main()
```

Basically you are reading the whole file and not resetting where the pointer is. Either close the file and reopen which will take more effort, or call the `seek()` function with parameter `0`.

Basically how files are `read` from is like a cursor in a text file when you are typing. Now hold the `->` key until you are at the end of file. Next time you try to read something and you didn't set your cursor back to the start, it will just read the `end of file` symbol and thinks it's empty.

`seek(0)` tells the file pointer or cursor ( from our example ) to go back to the start. `seek()` takes a parameter that is in bytes to go to that file's byte, zero being the start.

Answer (score 0):

the first time you call `data_mining()` the file is read, and the file read pointer ends up at the end of the file. Calling `text_file.seek(0)` at the beginning of `data_mining` will ensure the pointer always starts at the beginning of the file.